# Spring AOP @AfterThrowing - get and log called method details (not calling method)

Tags: java, spring, aop

**Main question** - I want to use Spring AOP to log the parameters of a method if that method runs into an error - i.e. if there is an Exception in the execution of that method and that exception is thrown to the calling method.

Can I do the above? Seems like @AfterThrowing logs the calling methods details, but not the called method (where the error actually occurred).

This is what I have -

**Tech Stack** -

1. Spring Boot 1.3.5

My @Aspect class -

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.spicedcider.service..*.*(..))", throwing = "e")
public void logExceptionContext(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable e) {
    Object[] params = joinPoint.getArgs();

    log.error("Exception while executing method below - ");
    log.error("[" + joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature() + "]");
    log.error("Exception message - " + e.getMessage());
    log.error("Full stack trace logged further below");

    log.error("Params for this method - ");
    for (Object object : params) {
        log.error(object == null ? "[is null]" : object.toString());
    }
}
```

The above works well - if the flow goes as below,

**Main calling method**

```
public void executeBusinessLogic(String var1, String var2) {
    /* some activities */
    String myName = "Spiced Cider";
    returnObject = anotherService.executeSubLogic(myName);

    /* more activities based on returnObject */
}
```

**Supporting method**

```
public Object executeSubLogic(String name) {
    /* an exception occurs here and is thrown to executeBusinessLogic() */
}
```

Now, the AOP logs this as below.

```
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - Exception while executing method below - 
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - [void executeBusinessLogic()]
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - Exception message - <message>
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - Full stack trace logged further below
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - Params for this method - 
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - <var1 value>
[ERROR] [..LoggingAspect.logExceptionContext] - <var2 value>
```

As can be seen it is logging the "calling method" and related items vs. the "called method" - where the error actually occurred.

**Reason why I need this** - this is from a debugging perspective. When an exception occurs, I need to know the params passed to the method where the exception occurred.

**Alternates considered** -

1. Now I can log every method entry and params using AOP - but I don't want to clutter the logs / performance - knowing the params is needed only when there was an exception.
2. I can of course log this in every method with a try/catch block, but that means having to repeat boilerplate code a lot.

I have searched many forums where there are details around how to get AOP to work etc. but could not find the above asked / discussed. This is the only other post (that I could find) which talks about called vs. calling - but is not an answer to this question - [Spring AOP with groovy: get called method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28474278/spring-aop-with-groovy-get-called-method)

Please let me know if we can do what I'm looking for / if this is even the correct (or efficient) way of doing this. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If everything is implemented correctly I would expect that the log output appears multiple times - once for each public, non-static method within a Spring component(!) throwing the error up the callstack. Is this really what you want? The same exception logged multiple times? Anyway, it seems that you want exactly that.

Some explanations come to mind for the observed behaviour:

- The class declaring method `executeSubLogic(..)` is **not** a Spring bean/component. Because you seem to use Spring AOP, not full-fledged AspectJ, the AOP framework can only intercept public methods of Spring components.
- The class declaring method `executeSubLogic(..)` is a Spring bean/component, but it does not implement an interface. In order to create a dynamic proxy for classes (not interfaces), Spring needs CGLIB, but for some reason the lib is not on your classpath.
- Your pointcut catches all method executions in package `com.spicedcider.service` incl. subpackages, but the class declaring method `executeSubLogic(..)` is **not** in that package.

Comment: Hi kriegaex - thank you for the details. Mine is case 2 above - the class with executeSubLogic(...) is an abstract base class and it does not implement an interface. I'll check to see if I can change that.